# How to hide a grouped column in visual studios or Report builder when the value of column returns as 0

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have grouped a column, when i run the query, report comes out fine however under grouped column if one or more column has values = 0 then the column header disappears. I want to hide this is column instead. See the attached images to better understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8ln6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BDNf.png)
Please advise

I used following formula to hide the column but nothing works.

```
=iif(Fields!column_name.Value=Nothing,True,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is for NULL values, you sound like you are simply looking for 0

```
=Fields!Field_Name.Value = 0

=IIf(Fields!Field_Name.Value > 0, False,True)
```

Comment: I have tried this but getting the following error

Comment: The Hidden expression for the tablix 'element status Grp' contains an error. Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Have you tried adding SUM(Fields!Field_Name.Value) ?

Comment: Yes i have tried this. All am trying to do it use  the table as a matrix. Splitting values of one column into mutiple columns and counting the value of it.

Comment: What kind of "SPLIT" do you mean? Your evaluation should match the same you are doing